# Existence of homomorphism between two groups

Tags: group-theory

Can there exist an onto group homomorphism from $S_5$ to $ S_4$ or from $S_5$ to $\mathbb Z_5$?Is it possible to write the homomorphism explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an argument which uses more than we need, which makes it more interesting perhaps.
Suppose that $\phi\colon S_5\rightarrow S_4$ is a group epimorphism. Then $\ker(\phi)$ is a normal subgroup of $S_5$, hence equal to $A_5$ or $S_5$, and $S_5/\ker(\phi)\simeq S_4$.
The case $\ker(\phi)=1$ would imply that $S_5\simeq S_4$, which is obviously wrong.
However, $S_4$ has $24$ elements, but $S_5/\ker(\phi)$ can only have $1$ or $2$ elements. This is a contradiction. The same argument works for the other case.

Comment: A good one .+1 for your answer @Burde

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

In $S_5$ if you take the cycle $s=(1 2 3 4 5)$ and the transposition $\tau=(12)$  we have  : $s^5=\text{id}$ and $\tau^2=\text{id}$

If $\sigma  \in S_4$  can you have $\sigma^5=\text{id}$  ?

If $\theta \in \Bbb Z_5$  can you have $2 \theta=\overline 0$ ?

Comment: thanx.I have got the required answer